# Draw a floating image HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I want to draw an image with HTML/CSS that "floats" above the main content. The position has to be relative to a table. Currently I am trying this:

```
<table>
  <tr><td><img class="float" src="..." />Table Heading</td></tr>
<table>
```

The CSS style has:

```
position:relative;
top:10px;
left:10px;
```

The image itself is pretty large (in terms of dimensions). The code positions the image properly, but the problem is that the table cell becomes very large (large enough to accommodate the image). I want the image to float above the table and not affect the table size. If I change the position to absolute, the table cell does not expand, but the image will be positioned relative to the screen, which I don't want.

So I'm wondering what is the correct way to draw a floating image relative to a table in HTML?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: float is a keyword in css, you might not want to have a css class with the same name ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the position on the table to relative and the position on the image to absolute. This way the image's absolute position will be relative to the table, not the document.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gLhNh/1)**

```
.float {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
table {
    border:1px solid #999;
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
}
```